# Replace freewheel with freehub?

Tags: road-bike, freewheel, diy, restoration

I have a Motobecane Super Mirage that I bought in 1977. I have another bike for regular use, and I've decided to completely rebuild the older one. I determined today that the freewheel teeth are worn down, so I need to replace that. I am just learning about freehubs. Can I replace the freewheel with a freehub setup? What factors do I need to keep in mind if doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to replace the hub (i.e. build the wheel with a new hub -- typically, its better to just get a new wheel), and then [respace the frame](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html#spreading) (i.e. coldset) to take the new hub.

It's easy still to find freewheels, so I'd recommend you just replace the freewheel.